# Can't compile simple C++ program, clarification needed

Tags: c++, syntax

I am borring this example from the material i am going over. According to textbook, all is well here.

Yet, when trying to compile these files, i am getting a problem (see below)

3 files

`Date.cpp:`

```
    #include "Date.h"

    Date::Date()
    {
        setDate(1,1,1900);
    }

    Date::Date(int month, int day, int year)
    {
        setDate(month, day, year);
    }
```

`Date.h:`

```
class Date
{
public:
    Date ();
    Date (int month, int day, int year);

    void setDate(int month, int day, int year);
private:
    int m_month;
    int m_day;
    int m_year;
};
```

`Main.cpp:`

```
#include "Date.h"

int main () 
{
    Date d1 ;

    return 1;
}
```

When trying to compile with `g++ *`, i get

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Date::setDate(int, int, int)", referenced from:
      Date::Date()  in cc8C1q6q.o
      Date::Date()  in cc8C1q6q.o
      Date::Date(int, int, int) in cc8C1q6q.o
      Date::Date(int, int, int) in cc8C1q6q.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When i declare `Date *d;` instead, program compiles.
When i declare `Date *d = new Date` instead, program fails.

What's going on here please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't provided a `setDate` method for your class. You declare it in the header file but you need to provide actual *code* for it as well.

The error you're seeing is the linker (`ld`) telling you that, although you have a piece of code trying to *call* that method, the linker has no idea where it is.

You need to provide the method, such as putting the following into `Date.cpp`:

```
void Date::setDate (int month, int day, int year) {
    m_month = month;
    m_day = day;
    m_year = year;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The function setDate that you care calling from both constructor is undefined

you need something like in your .cpp file

```
  void  Date::setDate(int month, int day, int year)
        {
            //code
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you never defined `Date::setDate()`